Identifying a WiFi module
I need help identifying this WiFi microcontroller. The pictures below should help. Perhaps there are firmware tests I can run to help identify this chip? (I am confident that this is a WiFi module because of the apparent antenna on the front of the chip as well as the communication protocol used on the larger electronic I found this on.)



As identified, it is a Tuya BK7231T module. See the OpenBeken project for alternative firmware and development.

It's a WB8P Wi-Fi module made by tuya.


Searching for WB8P which appears on the silkscreen found the FCC report WB8P Wi-Fi and Bluetooth Module for which the Product Overview is:

WB8P is a low-power embedded Wi-Fi module that Tuya has developed. It consists of a highly integrated RF chip (BK7231T) and several peripheral components, with an embedded Wi-Fi network protocol stack, Bluetooth network protocol, and robust library functions. WB8P also contains a low-power Arm Cortex-M4 MCU, 1T1R WLAN module, 256 KB static random-access
memory (SRAM), and 2 MB flash memory, and has extensive peripherals.
WB8P is an RTOS platform that integrates all function libraries of the Wi-Fi MAC and TCP/IP protocols. You can develop embedded Wi-Fi products as required.

BK7231T COB Hardware Design Guideline on the Tuya website about the BK7231T chip used on the Wi-Fi module. The Features contain:


Built-in low-power 32-bit CPU, 256 kbit static RAM, and 2 MB flash.
The maximum clock speed is 120 MHz.
Full functionality of IEEE 802.11b/g/n Wi-Fi connectivity.
Integrated Bluetooth Low Energy (LE) system.
The maximum output power is +17 dBm for 802.11b transmission.


